# Android jQuery AJAX for submit error

Tags: jquery, android, ajax

I built a simple mobile site that uses jQuery AJAX requests to post a wall feed to a page via form submission.

The code works perfectly on regular browsers and an ipad (not sure about iphone), but on an android, when I hit the form submit button it redirects to another page that just says "undefined."

Is there a known issue with jquery + ajax + android?

```
<form id="newPost" action="shout.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="50"/>
    What do you think? </br> <textarea name="message" id="message" maxlength="140"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Shout!" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    refresh_shoutbox();
    refresh_announcements();

    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: $('#newPost').attr('method'), 
            url: $('#newPost').attr('action'),
            data: $('#newPost').serialize(),
            success: function(html) {
                refresh_shoutbox();
                refresh_announcements();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
        useTransform: false,
        onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
            var target = e.target;
            while (target.nodeType != 1)
                target = target.parentNode;

            if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

function refresh_shoutbox() {
    var data = 'refresh=1';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "shout.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
            $("#shout").html(html);
            myScroll.refresh();
        }
    });
}

function refresh_announcements() {
    var data = 'refresh=1';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "announce.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
            $("#announce").html(html);
            myScroll.refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you've written.

Comment: Nevermind, its the default android browser's problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, and got the AJAX based element to maintain state. Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('#before_category_select').loadPage();

jQuery.fn.loadPage = function()
{

if($("#new-post-area").length > 0)
{

    $.getJSON('/home/cat_select_state.json', function(data){
        $.get('/posts/update_sub_cat/' + data.cat_state, function(data1){
           $("#sub-category-select").html(data1);
        })
    });
   }
}
```

The controller action that I call to get the state of the select elements, which is stored as session variables at the time of page submit:

```
  def cat_select_state
    @cat_session = {:cat_state => session[:new_post_category], :sub_cat_state => session[:new_post_sub_category]}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => @cat_session}
    end
  end
```

And finally, I used a default values for the select boxes, which are stored as session variables. If the session variable is null, the default value is the prompt message for the select box.

```
<%= collection_select :post_category, :id, @categories, :id, :name, 
                                                options = {:prompt => "Select a category", :selected => session[:new_post_category]} %>
```

The HTML for sub-category select element is rendered in the javascript file update_sub_cat.js.erb.

```
sub-category <%= collection_select :post_sub_category, :id, @sub_categories, :id, :name, 
                                        options = {:prompt => "Select a sub-category"} %>
```

Please suggest if you have any more improvements.